Гугл скрипт и гугл диск
Всем привет, подскажите есть задача, получить файли из гугл диска (файл формата zip) и записать содержания в гугл таблицу
function myFunction() {
  let file = DriveApp.getFolderById("1HFxkMapdlAvt5OXkrw_GhIocWPubw2xj")
  let tesst = file.getFiles()
  while (tesst.hasNext()) {
  var filettt = tesst.next();
    Logger.log(filettt.getDownloadUrl());
  } 
  
}

Получить доступ к папки получилось а дальше как получить данные и записать их не пойму

Файл формата zip это архив, врядли из него можно напрямую "получить данные". Для начала его надо распаковать и сохранить на диск исходную таблицу (там же таблица, как я догадываюсь?).
И потом к ней получать доступ, например через SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl().

да там таблица!

oshliaer
а каким штатным методам?

@oshliaer Очередной комментарий ради комментария? От  вас ни одной подсказки, ни в  моих вопросах, ни здесь конкретно, подозреваю, что и в других тоже. Покажите нам  штатный метод достать значения таблицы, не распаковывая zip.
